# how to change default color for the value not defined when we use scale_fill_manual

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot like below. As I am only focusing on  `name %in% c("A", "B", "C")` , I will not define the color for other names. By default, they were filled with dark grey. By not defining the color for those, I was able to plot D, E out without showing them in the legend.

Is it a way I can change this default color to light grey? If so , how?

[image]

```
# Load ggplot2
library(ggplot2)

# Create data
data <- data.frame(
  name=c("A","B","C","D","E") ,  
  value=c(3,12,5,18,45)
  )

# Barplot
ggplot(data, aes(x=name, y=value, fill=name)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")   +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("A"="red", "B"="green", "C"="blue") )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the argument `na.value` to change the default color to light grey like this:

```r
# Load ggplot2
library(ggplot2)

# Create data
data <- data.frame(
  name=c("A","B","C","D","E") ,  
  value=c(3,12,5,18,45)
)

# Barplot
ggplot(data, aes(x=name, y=value, fill=name)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")   +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("A"="red", "B"="green", "C"="blue"), 
    na.value = "lightgrey")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I already had forgotten `na.value`. Very elegant solution!